# Is there a variable type for comparators?

Tags: c#, variables, compare

Is there a variable type (something like `string`, `int`, or `bool`) for comparators? (`==`, `!=`, `<=`, `>=`, `>`, `<`) And if not, how does C# use them?

I can use

```
int integerVariable = 0;
```

but is there something I can use to do

```
comp comparatorVariable = ==;
```

?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx  All  about C# operators.

Comment: I suspect that you should be able to solve your *actual* problem using delegates. If you want to compare two doubles, but want to pick and choose which comparison operator to use, you can define a delegate like this: `Func<double, double, bool> comp = (a, b) => a < b;` Replace the `<` with the various operators. Then you can use it like this: `if (comp(10, 20)) { ... }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The various operators you've listed do not have a type no.  Objects have types.  You've listed operators, which are themselves not objects, and so have no type.  If you're interested in how the C# language uses operators, you can look at the language spec; section 7.3 of the C# 5.0 specs is titled "Operators" and is filled with information on how C# handles operators.

Answer (score -1):

C# provides a generic interface called `IComparable<T>`.

This interface has a single method: `int CompareTo<T>`

```
public interface IComparable<in T>
    {
        int CompareTo(T other);
    }
```

To implement the comparative operators (==, !=, <=, >=, >, <), you need to implement these operators on the class that inherits `IComparable` .

The date time "==" operator probably looks something like the following.

```
public static bool operator ==(DateTime d1, DateTime d2)
{
    return d1.CompareTo(d2) == 0;
}
```

Comment: `To implement the comparative operators (==, !=, <=, >=, >, <), you need to implement these operators on the class that inherits IComparable .`  That's strictly false.  You can absolutely override those operators on a type that doesn't implement `IComparable`.  It might be a good idea to override the operator on types implementing that interface, but it is by no means a requirement.  And in any case, the OP isn't asking how to override the operators, he's asking what their type is.

Comment: As for the implementation of the operator, [it's public](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,df6b1eba7461813b), the implementation is `public static bool operator ==(DateTime d1, DateTime d2) { return d1.InternalTicks == d2.InternalTicks; }`

Comment: @Servy I did not say you must use IComparable to implement the operators. I was just proposing a solution to the problem of implementing them, saying the class that implements the interface would be a good candidate for implenting the operators.

Comment: Your answer states: `To implement the comparative operators (==, !=, <=, >=, >, <), you need to implement these operators on the class that inherits IComparable.`  So yes, you did in fact claim that one needs to implement that interface to override those operators.  And once again, the question isn't even asking how you override the operators, it's asking what type they are.  You aren't answering that question.

Comment: @Servy Also, I did not say my implementation of the DateTime == operator was correct or exactly like implementation which I know is publicly available.  Once again it was a suggestion of something the OP might do to implement the operator on his class.

Comment: You said that the operator probably looks like what you showed.  It doesn't really look like what you showed at all, it looks like something rather different.  And once again, the question isn't asking how to override an operator, so you explaining how to override an operator isn't at all relevant to the question.

Comment: All right, let's calm down here. Please don't take technical critiques of an answer personally. I've cleaned up the comments that were starting to get a little heated.